# Changing ASP Included file and saving choice as a cookie

Tags: ajax, listview, asp-classic, grid, include

Ok, so I'm in the process of expanding my knowledge and need a step in the right direction, not necessarily an answer.

I am wanting to create a script for my eCommerce site that lets users choose between grid and list view on product listings pages.

The grid view will be called using an included file called "incgridview.asp" - the list view file is called "inclistview.asp".

Upon the user choosing an option from the drop down specifying which type of view they want, the respective file should be called. So if they select grid view, I need to load the incgridview.asp (list view will be loaded by default).

Once the selection is made, I need it to switch the view without reloading the page, and store a cookie for 7 days that remembers their selection. Of course, they would still have the option to switch back to the other view.

So basically I am switching which file is included upon user selection of the drop down. Im thinking maybe I need to use ajax but not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

***EDIT***
Ok, so this is what I am trying to use, on my file that actually includes the grid pages. It is throwing up this error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: '[object]'

/productsviewtest.asp, line 59

```
Dim listgridcookie
listgridcookie = Response.Cookies("atdviewcookie")("viewoption")
Select Case listgridcookie
    Case "list"
print"list view"
    Case "grid"
print "grid view"
    Case Else
    Response.Cookies ("atdviewcookie")("viewoption") = "grid"
    Response.Cookies ("atdviewcookie").Expires = DATE + 7
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
    End Select
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do so this might be totally irrelevant, but note that you can't do conditional includes in ASP. As in, `<%If [this] Then %> <!-- #include ... --> <%Else%> <!-- #include ... --> <%End If%>` won't work, or at least won't do what you expect it to do. (It'll include both files - that part happens long before any code is parsed, let alone executed.)

Answer (score 0):

here is a steps on your page load:

1) Check if cookies exists and what values are there, if it does not exists - create one with default value.

2) Based on value from cookies show div which has been loaded with data from proper include file.

3) When/if selection changes create/re-write cookies with expiration time you desire.

All what you need to build is JavaScript based switch to show one element and hide another.
If you like to use AJAX or JQuery - you can do it this way but for my taste it take away challenges of creating something you can be proud of.

This is based on your " page must not be reloaded upon changing selection" statement.

Comment: After thinking it through, it really doesn't matter if the page is reloaded, actually it may be better , I wasn't thinking that once the page has a cookie set, it can reload once to call the new include if that makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the one fall back of using the hidden div would be increased page load times, I need the pages to be as fast as possible to help with SEO.

Comment: To speed up load of the page you can use AJAX and Jquery. But having hidden div make sense. Once you cached your data you can reuse it and new load will be almost instantaneous. It will also speed up different kind of manipulations like paging, searches etc. Most important part of that is that cache can be user/session specific or for everyone use if it is stored on application level.AS example I would recommend look at careers site of CVS. From looks of it you will never guess how many hidden divs open-up via navigation.